# Escalamiento aplicacion nodejs en Digitalocean

Tags: nodejs, linux, apache, nginx

Trato de hacer lo siguiente: Tengo 1 formulario con algunos campos, este puede subir archivos (fotos, documentos, etc.) es simple,  y esto luego se visualiza en una lista de archivos en otra vista con una pequeña descripción. Cuando lo hice usando un solo nodo como servidor no había problema pues usé `multer` para recibir los archivos y `fs` para renombrarlos y filtrarlos según un patrón.

```
app.post("/archivo", upload.single('archivo'), filtro, (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.file);
    fs.rename(req.file.path, "./filtrado/" + req.file.originalname);
...... ................... ..
```

La cuestión es que mi aplicación tiene que tener **20k de usuarios concurrentes**, he estado haciendo algunas pruebas con Apache ab,usando 4 nodos de 1gb en Digitalocean con Nginx de proxy inverso y veo que soporta alrededor de 7k
(este solo en la vista que muestra los archivos, me falta testear el formulario)

He seguido los tutoriales de digitalocean, en cada dopplet creo una instancia de mi aplicación y lo balanceo con Nginx, con 1 instancia iba hasta a 800, con 2 hasta 2000, con 3 hasta 3000-4000 y con 4 hasta 7k,es obvio que necesito seguir escalando horizontalmente, pero según su experiencia ¿Cuál seria una forma recomendada de hacer esto? Pues el código en [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) es pequeño, no hay nada que optimizar, lo corro en modo producción, no uso Gzip ni compression pues Nginx ya usa.

Y con respecto a las prueba de carga aparte,no soy experto en ello pues nunca me preocupe hasta ahora en ello , pero como podría hacer una prueba completa a mi aplicación, los tutoriales son muy limitados en ese aspecto. y aparte de Apache ab cual me recomendarían, de antemanos muchas gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo planteas como si fuera un requisito. ¿Quieres decir 20k usuarios activos? ¿20k peticiones por segundo? Porque no creo que el requisito real sea la concurrencia... ¿no?

Comment: Si no respondes no podemos ayudarte ;). Benchmarking con [wrk](https://github.com/wg/wrk). Comienza **siempre** realizando los test en localhost. En tu caso, [HDD Bechmarking](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108838/how-can-i-benchmark-my-hdd). Si tienes una tasa de escritura digamos de unos 65Mb/s y todos los usuarios quieren subir una foto de 300k, tienes una concurrencia de 216 usuarios y no puedes optimizar nada, tan sólo cambiar de HDD. De verdad te piden concurrencia?

Comment: ¿Estas usando Cluster?

Comment: Para david , eso mismo pense ,les dije lo mismo , pero me piden 20k conexiones concurrentes,si me piden concurrencia,y en cuanto a german uso cluster pero eso no afecta en nada pues los dopplets o nodos que uso en digitalocean usan 1gb y son de 1 nucleo , lo que estoy haciendo es correr en 4  dopplets la aplicacion en el mismo puerto , en una red privada , luego en el servidor principal que tiene nginx uso el balanceador de carga para enviar las peticiones a los 4 servidores segun la carga que tengan.